# Performance testing of Cordova apps

Tags: performance, mobile, android, ios

Recently I started working on cordova application coded in AngularJS (targeted for Android and iOS). I must do some performance tests of few scenarios to check framerate and execution time of js. It's my first time developing mobile app in Cordova and I can't find any good tool to use. I tried to use chrome dev tools but as they show valuable info, this tools are designed for manual profiling and I need to run multiple iterations of tests to make results more reliable. Scenarios consists of simple cases like: change view and scroll. Do you know any tools that are simple enough to write few scenarious and do some tests?

Answer (score 1):

For Android :After compiling the cordova project and get the APK file install it to a device and use Android device Monitor at Android Studio or Eclipse (what ever the ADT you are using)

Or

after compiling it to android open the android platform folder thru the Android Studio or Eclipse (what ever the ADT you are using) and then use the Android device Monitor.

or After installing the APK to mobile use jmeter to test the performance. 
https://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi6udL409rPAhXIvY8KHaPQBDQQtwIIIjAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DgmLq4tLfOTg&usg=AFQjCNELe3qd-ZjCRHWiURyEbLa6gZxCCg&sig2=inW4tAoskjfrofEAUqaCtg

IOS: After compiling open the Xcode project thru Xcode and use instruments to test the performance.

Comment: It looks like a good manual tool for performance testing but I need something more automatic. Are there any chance to run some iterative tests in Android device Monitor?

Answer (score 1):

The cordova application can be run as a website in your localhost.
So apart from testing the APK or IPA you can run a performance test on the website.

Comment: It's not the best idea really. Only if you have pure web app without any native features (which are sometimes pretty laggy).